# Difference between these 'killing' words

Tags: meaning, difference, legalese

Please explain the difference between these words. When to use which?

```
to kill/killing
to murder/murder
to slaughter/slaughter
to slay/slaying
homicide
massacre
```

Comment: All of them are usable, depending on the context. Please give some context.

Comment: I want to understand the context in which I should use one over the others. That is the point of my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> to kill/killing

Most basic/versatile expression.

> to murder/murder

Implies the voluntary killing of a sentient being. In US law, there is a distinction between "murder" (intentionally killing someone) vs. "manslaughter" (unintentionally killing a person); murder is considered even worse.

Depending on the context, "murder" may have a sense of cruelty.

> to slaughter/slaughter

Literally to kill an animal prior to butchery. When used in other contexts it has an overtone of being very messy or cruel, because of the association with killing a defenseless animal and then dismembering it. Thus, it has the implication of completeness or thoroughness; an army that was slaughtered was killed brutally; a sports team that was "slaughtered" was beaten by a painfully large margin.

> to slay/slaying

Somewhat archaic. Focuses on the act more than the results; may be considered a "deed" or significant action. May also imply a sense of struggle. "He slew the wolf" sounds like he fought with it on equal terms (or terms that were not favorable to him), and accomplished something by killing it; "he murdered the wolf" focuses on having killed a living being, and has a pronounced tone of disapproval.

> homicide

Literally killing a person. More of a legal term.

> massacre

Killing of a large number of people (or "multiple people" at least--the Boston Massacre actually only resulted in the deaths of five people after all). Usually there is a tone of disapproval, though in metaphoric usage it's similar to "slaughter" above ("We massacred them" in the context of a sporting event means our team won by a large margin.)

Answer (score 5):

These terms vary mostly in number and moral connotation:

**Kill**: a generic term for ending something's life. Unique in that it
does not have a strong moral connotation.

**Murder**: to criminally and intentionally kill an individual. Has a
strongly negative moral connotation. A accidental killing of an
individual would be termed '**manslaughter**.'

**Slaughter**: to kill many or brutally. Originally used exclusively to
refer to the killing of animals, if applied to humans it communicates
a killing, "as if they were animals." Can have a neutral or negative
moral connotation:

- "I slaughtered my cow yesterday" - neutral
- "It was a slaughter of innocents" - negative

**Slay**: an older, less frequently used equivalent of kill. Frequently
used in fantasy contexts.

**Homicide**: a more precise term for a human killing another human.
Typically refers to the crime of murder.

**Massacre**: similar to slaughter: a brutal killing of many. Almost
always used refers to killing of people, and almost always has a
strong negative connotation.

Comment: America (and many other English-speaking countries) have the legal concept of "killing in self-defense".  This concept includes killing in defense of others.  In some jurisdictions, it even applies to the defense of property.  "Killing in self-defense" is neither murder nor homicide.  Also, there is the concept of "justifiable homicide", which is a legal homicide.

Answer (score 1):

To a great extent, the rest of these words are synonyms or clarifications of "to kill" or of one another.

- To kill: cause to die
- Murder: kill with intent or forethought; not accidental
- Slaughter: kill with relish or abandon, or large number
- Slay: another form of slaughter?
- Homicide: noun form; murder
- Massacre: noun or verb form; slaughter